# Confgure ESLint to underline const, let and other ES6 features

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint, ecmascript-5

My project need to support old browsers and I want to find potential bugs like using `let`, `const` and such. How do I configure ESLint?

This is my current `eslinrrc.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "commonjs": true,
        "es6": false,
    },
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 5,
    },
//...
}
```

PS: Yes, I know I can use babel, but I can't really. To risky to rewrite the build process at the moment.

Comment: And that does not work? Are other rules working as expected?

Comment: Yes, everything else works as expected. I should have probably mentioned that I'm using ESLint with VSCode.